# Adding dynamically selected value to LOV in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle-apex

I have problem with multi-select LOVs in Apex 5.
I want to do, in programmatic way, select values in multi-select LOV.
For example I press button and some value will be selected in LOV.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a Select List item that is set to allow multiple values then your button could execute this Javascript:

```
$('#P123_MY_MULTI_SELECT option[value="AAA"]').attr('selected',true);
$('#P123_MY_MULTI_SELECT option[value="BBB"]').attr('selected',true);
```

... etc.

Alternatively, you could use a dynamic action, but it wouldn't be any simpler.  It would define the affected elements using a jQuery selector:

```
#P123_MY_MULTI_SELECT option[value="AAA"],#P123_MY_MULTI_SELECT option[value="BBB"]
```

... and the action would be to execute Javascript code:

```
$(this.affectedElements)..attr('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe the easiest example:

1. Create APEX item eg. `P1_MULTIPLE`

Type = `Select list`

Allow Multi Selection = `Yes`

List of Values > Type = `Static Values`

List of Values > Static values = `STATIC:Display1;Return1,Display2;Return2`

2. Create button eg. `SET_VALUES`
3. Create dynamic action

Event = `Click`

Selection type = `Button`

Button = `SET_VALUES`

4. Create true action within DA from step 3

Action = `Set Value`

Set Type = `JavaScript Expression`

JavaScript Expression = `['Return1', 'Return2']`

Selection Type = `Item(s)`

Item(s) = `P1_MULTIPLE`

5. Test it.

basically, if you want to change value(s) of the multi select list you need to pass array of value(s).

With pure jQuery (without APEX DA):

```
$("#P1_MULTIPLE").val(['Return2', 'Return1'])
```

Comment: OK, and how to do this when my multi-select list have not static values but it's based on SQL query?

Comment: I don't understand your question here. You wrote: `For example I press button and some value will be selected in LOV.`. It doesn't matter if it's static LOV or dynamic. Do you know what values you want to make selected in your select list field?